# Bigquery Streaming Inserts - Cannot find log entries

Tags: google-bigquery

Im looking into stackdriver BQ logs, and cannot see any entries for streaming inserts, which execute:

tabledata.insertAll

Is there a different place to find these?  Bigtable since it uses that under the covers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, there is no audit logs for BigQuery streaming inserts. There is on-going work related to this. You can see this [FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/119254941) about that in the public issue.

Comment: That link is to Google's internal systems.